# MDX Query to create a calculated measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

My requirement:
Calculate the Gross Margin Amount which is difference of PL Amount for Revenue and Cost of Sales.

Revenue and Cost of Sales belong to a PL Category dimension and PL Amount is the measure.

To calculate the difference, I have written the following. How do I proceed further?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENT CUBE [Measures].[Gross Margin Amount] AS 
(
([Profit and Loss].[Profit and Loss].[Category].&[100],[Measures].[PL Amount]) - 
([Profit and Loss].[Profit and Loss].[Category].&[200],[Measures].[PL Amount])
)
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Measure';",
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Without that it may be difficult to help you. However, assuming you have this code in your calculation script, the correct syntax would be `CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Gross Margin Amount] AS ...` instead of `CREATE MEMBER CURRENT CUBE [Measures].[Gross Margin Amount] AS ...`

Comment: Any you will need a comma before the `FORMAT_STRING` and you should omit the final `",` after the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a cube designer so a little unsure. Does adding in the `AGGREGATE` function help:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENT CUBE [Measures].[Gross Margin Amount] AS 
(
AGGREGATE([Profit and Loss].[Profit and Loss].[Category].&[100],[Measures].[PL Amount]) - 
AGGREGATE([Profit and Loss].[Profit and Loss].[Category].&[200],[Measures].[PL Amount])
),
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Measure';,
```

Comment: did this help at all?

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply, it did help a lot. Thanks and you were right

Comment: excellent (you might like to hit the green tick button if it answered the question)